# How to export functions in typescript

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

Total Typescript newbie. I'm working on a cdk project. I have a class (stack) that is getting massive. So I want to offload a bunch of methods into other files to keep it manageable.

This works:

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as lambda        from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';                // need for Runtime
import * as lambda_nodejs from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs';

const TAG = "sn-v1-";

export class SnProdStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
      super(scope, id, props);

      // Lambda: Get stuff from Sigfox API
      // ---------------------------------
      
      const testLambda = new lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'sigfox-get', {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
        entry: 'lambda/sn-prod/sigfox-get.js',
        handler: 'handler',
        functionName: TAG + 'sigfox-get',
        description: 'Get all devices from Sigfox API.',
        memorySize: 256,
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(360)
      });
    }
}
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
// class file
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as lambda        from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';                // need for Runtime
import * as lambda_nodejs from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs';

import { genSigfoxGetLambda } from './sn-prod/api-gw';

export class SnProdStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
      super(scope, id, props);      
      const testLambda = this.genSigfoxGetLambda;
    }
}



// method file
import { SnProdStack } from '../sn-prod-stack';

import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as lambda        from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';                // need for Runtime
import * as lambda_nodejs from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs';

const TAG = "sn-v1-";

export function genSigfoxGetLambda(this: SnProdStack) {
    const testLambda = new lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'sigfox-get', {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
        entry: 'lambda/sn-prod/sigfox-get.js',
        handler: 'handler',
        functionName: TAG + 'sigfox-get',
        description: 'Get all devices from Sigfox API.',
        memorySize: 256,
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(360)
      });
      return testLambda;
}
```

This is a tiny minimal reproducible example. The whole code is enormous, with 10 or 20 of each thing. My plan is to use factory methods for each type of tying I need to make and pass in an options object. Right now, the problem is that the code I've written does nothing at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing at all"?

Comment: `const testLambda = this.genSigfoxGetLambda;` isn't calling the function, just assigning it.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter OK... Why does the first version work. That's doing the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: No, the first example you're assigning a new instance to `testLambda`. The second is assigning the imported function, you need to actually call the function to get the return value, i.e. `const testLambda = this.genSigfoxGetLambda(this);`.

Comment: Aha. `const testLambda = this._genSigfoxGetLambda();` with `private _genSigfoxGetLambda = genSigfoxGetLambda;` works. Very confusing language this.

Answer (score 2):

To export a function, we need to add the `export` directive and to make it available to other files outside of its current folder.

You are already using the `export` keyword, so now all you need to do is place an `index.ts` file in every folder.

For example, if we have this directory structure...

```
.
├── main.ts
└── module
    ├── a.ts
    └── index.ts
```

...and we wish to export a function from `a.ts` and use it in `main.ts`, then the function must use the `export` keyword and `index.ts` must export it from `module/`.

```
// a.ts
export const foo = () => { return 'bar'; };
```

```
// index.ts
export * from './a';
```

Then, we may import the function.

```
// main.ts
import { foo } from './module';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this from your main stack

```
import cdk = require("@aws-cdk/core");
import { MyFirstStack } from "../lib/my-first-stack";
import { StepFunctionStack } from "../lib/step-function-stack";

const app = new cdk.App();
const myFirstStack = new MyFirstStack(app, "stackName");
const stepFunctionStack = new StepFunctionStack(app, "stepFunctionStackName");

// If you need to add a dependency on one of your stacks
myFirstStack.addDependency(stepFunctionStack);
```

Then you can have the other stacks in the location imported from above, in my example its back 1 folder and in a lib folder..

Here is something what one of them stacks would look like

```
import { Construct, Stack, StackProps } from "@aws-cdk/core";

export class MyFirstStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: App, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    const properties: StackProps = {
      env: {
        region: "us-east-1",
        account: <account>,
      },
    };

    super(scope, id, properties);

    const lambda = create_lambda()

    create_lambda(){
    // code to create lambda etc. 
}
```